# How to convert Ethereumj byte arrays to Strings?

Tags: transactions, addresses, ethereumj, java

Ethereumj gives a lot of byte arrays, when the equivalent would be a string in Bitcoin. A few examples (in Scala)

```
ECKey.getAddress // returns Array[Byte], need String

Transaction.getHash // returns Array[Byte], need String

Transaction.getNonce // returns Array[Byte], need Int (or BigInteger)
```

Are the Strings supposed to be Hex encoded byte arrays? So, for example, I would do:

```
val addr = Hex.encodeBytes(ECKey.getAddress)

val txHash = Hex.encodeBytes(Transaction.getHash) 

val txNonce = new BigInteger(Transaction.getNonce)
```

Which of the above are right?